# Using same angular controller several places on the same page

Tags: angularjs

I would like to have a bootstrap navigation tab with unread message count.
Also, on the Messages page I need to display current messages and delete them whenever asked.
The problem is it appears the value in scope is not changed for the second div. I made a plunker with the demo - the issue is that second instance is not updated as expected. What am I missing? New to angular. Thank you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/O2ZduEP5JDkN219jXiNI

Comment: Consider to extract reused piece of html with logic into [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry - directives and templates are next in line!

Comment: check out http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-communicating-between-controllers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you're creating two `AppController` with different scopes:

```html
<body ng-controller="AppController"> <!-- here -->
  {{message}}
  <button type="button" ng-click="changeMe()">Click me</button>
  <div ng-controller="AppController"> <!-- and here -->
    <span>Second instance:</span>
    <span>{{message}}</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

When you click the button only `message` in the first scope will get updated. I don't know if this is intentional or not. If you want two scopes you should use a shared resource and update this, otherwise you could just remove the second controller.

- Same scope: http://plnkr.co/edit/MblFnvLzbKonYzw8lZWr?p=preview
- Different scopes, shared resource: http://plnkr.co/edit/65Y0Kc0h8NIExwmLLydn?p=preview

You also have an error in your `clickMe` function:

```js
$scope.changeMe = function() {
  $scope.message = "changed";
  // $scope.changeMe is triggered from ng-click, which is wrapped in an $apply
  // the following line will there cause an "Error: $apply already in progress" exception
  $scope.$apply();
};
```